# GLKit projection

Tags: opengl-es, projection

So I am trying to draw and rotate a cube using GLKit on an iPad. My problem is that as the cube rotates it seems as the aspect ratio changes with it, squeezing it as it rotates. What I mean can be seen in the three images that follow where the cube is rotating counterclockwise for 90 degrees. Although at the beginning(first image) the ratio width/height of the cube is approx. 1/2 which I have set by

```
GLKMatrix4 scaleMatrix=GLKMatrix4MakeScale(0.5, 1., 0.3);
```

as it turns it gets "squeezed" to end up after a pi/2 turn,with the side that was the base (before the turn) to be double the height(third image). I believe my mistake is in the arguments I pass to `GLKMatrix4MakePerspective`but as I am not very comfortable with all the calls to openGL methods and what each does I put also some parts of my code that I believe could have some connection to that, after the images.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
- (void)draw{
//just a quaternion that rotates the cube
GLKQuaternion glkq=GLKQuaternionMake(_quat.x,_quat.y,_quat.z,_quat.w);
GLKMatrix4 rotationMatrix=GLKMatrix4MakeWithQuaternion (glkq);

GLKMatrix4 scaleMatrix=GLKMatrix4MakeScale(0.5, 1., 0.3);
GLKMatrix4 translateMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.,0.,0.);

GLKMatrix4 modelMatrix =GLKMatrix4Multiply(translateMatrix,
                            GLKMatrix4Multiply(scaleMatrix,rotationMatrix));

GLKMatrix4 viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 0);
effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(viewMatrix, modelMatrix);


effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(45.0f), 3./4., 3, -5);

[effect prepareToDraw];

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleVertices);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleColors);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
}
```

I am not sure if you maybe need some other parts of the code to tell me what I doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix multiplication as a series of geometric transformations works from right to left and is not commutative. That is, given a rotation matrix `R` and scale matrix `S`, the product `S x R` means "rotate by `R` and then scale by `S`", which is a different result from "scale by `S` and then rotate by `R`" (as given by the product `R x S`).

You're scaling after rotating: instead of squishing a cube into a rectangular prism and then rotating it, you're rotating a cube and then squishing the resulting image. Reverse your multiplication of `scaleMatrix` and `rotationMatrix` and you should see the result you expect.

(Also, your `translateMatrix` specifies a translation of zero, so multiplying it into the model view matrix does nothing. If it was nonzero, though, in what order should you multiply it into your model view matrix?)

Comment: Thanks, rickster, yes that was exactly the problem I should first scale then rotate. Concerning the translation I suppose it should be last(on the left side)? otherwise would not rotate around the centre of the object? I do not know I have to try...